# Is Auto_Increment supported in Oracle using Liquibase

Tags: oracle, auto-increment, liquibase

I want to add an auto_increment column in an oracle database using liquibase script.

I have tried using the `auto_increment` attribute in liquibase :

```
<column name="SUPPLEMENT_ID" type="INTEGER" autoIncrement="true" >
<constraints primaryKey="true"></constraints> 
</column>
```

If oracle supports auto_increment, how can I achieve it using liquibase scripts?

Comment: what is your oracle version? autoincriment is only available from version 12

Comment: And what is your Liquibase version? Are you aware that there is no `auto_increment` option in Oracle? If at all it would be `supplement_id integer generated always as identity`

Comment: I'm currently using oracle 12. Does it support?

Comment: Oracle 12c supports IDENTITY columns using the syntax Horse describes. According to [Liquibase Jira site,](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-1731) the latest versions should support auto-increment for Oracle 12c. [Find out more](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/pull/416)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDENTITY columns are introduced in oracle 12c which allows users to create auto increment columns

But if you are using older versions you have to model the column with sequence and triggers as there is no such option as auto_increment or identity.

Please see this answer on how to do it in both cases
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11296469/8330426

Answer (score 1):

According to @APC's comment under the question, Liquibase supports Oracle auto increment since version 3.4.0. See https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-1731.